# Transaction rollback doesnt work

Tags: magento-1.8, database, transaction

I have the following code in my admin controller:

```
if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_dealers']['tmp_name'])) {
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        try {
            $connection->beginTransaction();

            $connection->query('TRUNCATE TABLE `dealer`');

            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_dealers']['tmp_name'], "r");

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ",")) !== false) {
                $import = "INSERT INTO `dealers` ..."

                $connection->query($import);
            }

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('...');

            fclose($handle);

            $connection->commit();               
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $connection->rollback(); //this doesnt work
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('...');
        }
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('...');
    }
}
```

It's supposed to rollback the table if some error occurs, but it doesn't. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was suspecting, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is causing the transaction to commit.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Magento there are two cases:
1. if you enable Mage::getIsDeveloperMode(). If there are error happend it will throw Exception. In this case you will be fine.

2. If you don't enable: DeveloperMode() in Magento. If an error happend it will log (Mage::log($errorMessage, Zend_Log::ERR). You code will be execute one by one if it is an error, It will rollback in case have an exception
3. After commit. Magento also call some function. I think maybe the exception throw in that function.

`PHP
$adapterKey = spl_object_hash($this->_getWriteAdapter());
if (isset(self::$_commitCallbacks[$adapterKey])) {
    $callbacks = self::$_commitCallbacks[$adapterKey];
    self::$_commitCallbacks[$adapterKey] = array();
    foreach ($callbacks as $index => $callback) {
        call_user_func($callback);
    }
}`

Comment: The catch block gets executed,  the message passed in `addError` shows on the screen, but the table has the records that were imported before the Exception

Comment: After commit. Magento also call some function. I think maybe the exception throw in that function.

$adapterKey = spl_object_hash($this->_getWriteAdapter());
            if (isset(self::$_commitCallbacks[$adapterKey])) {
                $callbacks = self::$_commitCallbacks[$adapterKey];
                self::$_commitCallbacks[$adapterKey] = array();
                foreach ($callbacks as $index => $callback) {
                    call_user_func($callback);
                }
            }

Comment: If that was the case 3, it would be fine. But some of the .csv lines might result in invalid queries (I've put some incorrect data to simulate)

Comment: As I told about case 1. If it is no exception, just error. It will log not throw Exception. To simulate it you can use throw directly in code. And see the result.